# considerably slower query when using high offset

Tags: mysql, database, left-join, innodb

here is my query  , it considerably slower when i use a high offset , why is that ? is there any cure for this ?

```
   offset 15 =>  0.9747  seconds

    SELECT `users`.*, count(`user_bets`.`id`) as bets, count(`user_bet_details`.`id`) as wins
    FROM `users`
    LEFT JOIN `user_bets` ON `user_bets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `user_bet_details` ON `user_bet_details`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `user_bet_details`.`status` = 1 
    GROUP BY `users`.`id`
     LIMIT 15, 10
```

and

```
  offset 2510 => 26.2188  seconds 

SELECT `users`.*, count(`user_bets`.`id`) as bets, count(`user_bet_details`.`id`) as wins
    FROM `users`
    LEFT JOIN `user_bets` ON `user_bets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `user_bet_details` ON `user_bet_details`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `user_bet_details`.`status` = 1 
    GROUP BY `users`.`id`
     LIMIT 2510, 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed difference is likely coming from the number of rows that the server must generate to satisfy the query.  For the first case, it only needs to generate 25 rows of the result set. For the second, it must generate 2520 rows.

Since the order is not apparently critical (based on looking at the specified query), perhaps you could change it to do the "paging" using the user id value (assuming it increments in a somewhat predictable fashion). Add a WHERE clause specifying the user id range of interest and forgo the LIMIT clause.  For example, perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT `users`.*, count(`user_bets`.`id`) as bets, count(`user_bet_details`.`id`) as wins
    FROM `users`
    LEFT JOIN `user_bets` ON `user_bets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `user_bet_details` ON `user_bet_details`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
               and `user_bet_details`.`status` = 1 
    WHERE `users`.`id` >= 1 and `users`.`id` <= 10
    GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

This would likely be more efficient to run, but more tricky to get the desired number of rows if `id` does not increment by 1 (which seems likely).  You could still use a LIMIT clause and a somewhat larger range each time and then specify the lower limit appropriately on the next call (again I am assuming this is for paging results).

But before doing that, you might [check the optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) of your query.  If, for example, you do not have indexes available on the join tables (on `user_bets.user_id`, `user_bet_details.user_id`, and `user_bet_details.status` in particular), then that could make a huge difference.  I didn't really think about the times specified at first, but 26 seconds to generate that query seems exceedingly long.  It sounds as if some indexes might need to be created.